# How do I get Parallels Plesk to only respond to a specific host, not ANY host?

Tags: plesk

I'm trying to get my Parallels Plesk Admin Panel to *only* respond to *one* host, not every host that points to the machine. Can this be done in Parallels Plesk 11.x?

I assumed that I'd be able to configure this through the <del>Apache</del> Nginx config files, but I haven't been able to locate where that might be.

So to be clear, I want the admin panel accessible on i.e. `admin.domain.com`, whilst unavailable on `www.clientdomain.com`, even though they're both on the same server and the same IP.

Comment: It would be better to post your answer as an answer instead of making it part of the question.

Comment: Right you are, I'll do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out, that what I want to do is not possible.
From the Parallels Plesk forums:

> You can't "bind" domain names to ports. You have one of a few options:
>
> 1. Change the default plesk port 8443 to something else
> 2. Create a proxy of `http://admin.yourdomain.com` that resolves to `http://yourserver:some-rare-port`
> 3. Have 2 IPs on your server (one resolves your admin domain while the other is your clients domains), then with a firewall CLOSE all connections to port 8443 on your clients IP address but allow only such a connection to your admin domain's IP address.

From [Parallels Plesk Forums](http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?296314-Getting-the-Admin-Panel-to-only-respond-to-ONE-host-not-ALL).